# Git (github), forked repo with submodule and commits

Tags: git, github

I'm quite new to git...

Let's assume, that there is a repo  on github. Lets call it main repo on fake address: `https://github.com/userA/mainrepo`.

The repo has a submodule, which is an another repo:

```
<local_path>\Submodule => https://github.com/userA/submodule
```

Now let's assume that userB made a fork of of mainrepo `https://github.com/userA/mainrepo` => `https://github.com/userB/mainrepo`) and fork of submodule (`https://github.com/userA/submodule` => `https://github.com/userB/submodule`).

Now userB clones his mainrepo. The submodule directory is empty.

Now questions:

1. How to "reconnect" the local submodule directory to `https://github.com/userB/mainrepo`?
2. UserB did point 1. After that he changed some files in submodule, went to that directory, did commit and push. `https://github.com/userB/submodule` got updated. UserB also modified some file in root of mainrepo. UserB did a commit of mainrepo and pushed. At that point to mainrepo the modified file is sent together with information that submodule got "reconnected" (.gitmodules probably).

Now user is doing a pull request to merge changes from `https://github.com/userB/submodule` to `https://github.com/userA/submodule`. All fine now.
But when user is doing a pull request to merge changes from `https://github.com/userB/mainrepo`  to `https://github.com/userA/mainrepo`, the submodule reconnect is about to be merged as well.

How to do a commit of myrepo in such situation?

Answer (score 0):

found it.

check changes:

```
git status

git rm <submodule_directory>
git clone -b <submodule_branch> https://github.com/userB/submodule submodule
git <submodule_directory> add -f https://github.com/userB/submodule submodule
```

Do the work, commit and push module

On the repo:

```
git reset --hard
git submodule update

git status
```